# Receiving a String collection as a query param in Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, spring-mvc

When using REST query params, is there a best practice on how to send a service a collection of Strings? Should I just make them comma delimited in the query string? Also, will Spring be able to map query string to a collection type, say an ArrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a example for you, as following request parameters:

```
['abc', 'edf', 'ghi']
```

You can concat this strings to your url like:

```
http://xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx?str=abc&str=edf&str=ghi
```

and your contoller should declare like:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public void test(@RequestParam("str[]") String[] strArr)
```

even you can submit these by a form like:

```
<form method='post' action='/'>
    <input type='text' name='str' value='abc'/>
    <input type='text' name='str' value='edf'/>
    <input type='text' name='str' value='ghi'/>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```